# ionic command still not found after installing ionic and ionic CLI

Tags: ionic-framework

l am trying to run ionic on my mac. l am currently on EL Capitan. l have installed the ionic CLI,npm and ionic itself by following the instructions on the ionic home page. l get the response -bash: ionic: command not found everytime l run ionic start sample or ionic start sample tabs .

Answer (score 3):

Did you used this in the command-line-interface:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Maybe something went wrong through the installation

Comment: It's happening to me too, on El Capitan. For some reason I have to type sudo before running any ionic command otherwise I get the bach error. I have tried installing and reinstalling using that line of code in your post there.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy try chmod 776 -R in your app's root folder

Comment: Yea I figured out that that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

I added 'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm' in my path and its works very well

Comment: thanks it worked. I have edited the path variable for android sdk. that seems  to have caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

l resolved this issue weeks after posting this in 2015, thought l post an answer to anyone who might need it.

It was all to do the path for the node modules. So to resolve it l added the node module path to mt profile and it worked.

Happy coding.

Comment: can you pls explain this

Answer (score 0):

check path variable in your environment variable. you must add the address of npm in path variable you can find it in c:/user/xxxx/appdata/roaming/npm.